# Do I have to uninstall old python versions to update to a new one on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have python 3.2 installed and I want to know if I have to uninstall earlier versions before installing newer ones.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which OS you are using.

Comment: There. Windows it is.

Comment: Both will work concurrently but removing older version would be clean.

Comment: No you do not but if you are on windows you will have to name your newer version of Python something else for example "python2" or "python33" so that there is no conflict when it searches the path for an executable. If you have two python interpreters both named python, only one will work when you type "python <args>" Also you need to install them in different folders because they have different libraries which you should keep separate.

Comment: @ShashankGupta So it would be better to just uninstall the old one?

Comment: It's up to you. Obviously it would be better to uninstall the old one before installing the new one, but if you need both versions, then its possible to keep both.

Comment: Installing Python 3.3 (or 3.4, etc.) alongside 3.2 is a lot easier than installing, say, 3.2.1 alongside 3.2.0. Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, you should skim [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) if you plan on having two Python installations with different X.Y versions on the same Windows system. Most Windows Python users don't realize they can get the same benefits from shebang lines that Unix users do—e.g., double-clicking a .py file can open in 3.2 or 3.3 depending on what the first line says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install all the Python X.Y versions you want, but include Python 3.3 or later (last is best, or reinstall it after all the others) to get the Python Launcher that @abarnert mentioned in his comments.  It is also available as a [standalone installer](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher).

Earlier versions than 3.3 should not register extensions, so the launcher installed by 3.3 or later will remain the default handler for `.py` files.

From the command line:

```
py -2        # launch latest 2.x version installed.
py -3        # latest 3.x
py -3.2      # run exact version
py -3.2-32   # run 32-bit version on 64-bit system.
```

So you can even have mixed 32-bit and 64-bit installations.

The environment variable `PY_PYTHON` can be set to specify the default Python to run.

In scripts, add a comment of the following forms below to use that version of Python when the script is double-clicked or run from command line via `py script.py`:

```
#!python2
#!python3
#!python3.2
#!python3.2-32
```

See [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) for further details.

Comment: I uninstalled 3.2 and installed 3.3, but pygame is gone. What happened?

Comment: Most add-ons are Python version-specific.  Did you install PyGame for 3.3? (https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3.msi).

Comment: I got it working but I had to change the default 'Python Launcher for Windows' to the python console in the Python33 folder. Is it possible to still open it with the 'Python Launcher'?

Comment: Yes, with any of the techniques in this post.  `py -3.3 script.py`, adding `#!python3.3` to the script, or setting the environment variable `PY_PYTHON=3.3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple versions of Python on Windows, but only the last version you installed will be used by default: when double-clicking a `.py` file in Windows Explorer, when typing just `python` at the command line, etc. "Edit in IDLE" on the context menu also uses the last version you installed. To use other versions you'll need to specify the full path of the version you want. Also, if you use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, there's only one of those, and the scripts in the directories specified in `PYTHONPATH` may or may not work with whatever version of Python you happen to be running. This can be worked around by writing a batch file that sets `PYTHONPATH` before launching Python.

Comment: The part about double-clicking a `.py` file, running it directly from the command line, etc. isn't true if you have a [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) launcher. I believe if at least one of your Python versions is 3.3 or greater, you have it automatically; otherwise, you have to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It generally depends on what OS you are running and how you installed your python. Under linux or Mac OSX, you don't need to unistall the previous version. I am not sure how things are handled for Windows.